# How is the download file name chosen and is there a way to change it?

Tags: pdf

I have a link to a file not on my server:

```
<a href="history.nasa.gov/monograph15b.pdf">NASA</a>
```

I would like to make it so that when a visitor clicks on the link to download, the name that would pop up for the PDF would be NASA.pdf, and not monograph15b.pdf.

Is this possible in any language?

Comment: Are you using any particular language?

Comment: the page is a php file, but i can use html, jvavscript, etc..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you aren't going to host the file yourself, you may be able to read in the file contents and then send those contents directly to the browser with the appropriate headers.

Note that this will be slow because you'll be re-downloading the file from NASA each time your PHP page runs.

```
<?php
$filename = "http://history.nasa.gov/monograph15b.pdf";
$outputfilename = "NASA.pdf";

header("Content-Type:  application/pdf");
header("Content-Disposition:  attachment; filename=\"" . basename($outputfilename) . "\";" );
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding:  binary");
readfile("$filename");
?>
```

This approach also requires that PHP be configured so that [fopen()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) can handle reading a file over HTTP.

Comment: thanks, this definitely works.

Do you know if something like this is possible client side - if for example, the server doesn't have access to a pdf, but the user does? Maybe in javascript?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.  Can you explain a little more?

Comment: for example, nasa has a few pdf's that can only be accessed if the user is logged in. 
I presume the script downloads the pdf and then sends it to the user. In this case, the script wouldn't have access to the pdf as it isn't logged in to NASA's servers.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hmmm.  I can't think of a good way to do that off the top of my head.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to really do that is to first download the file in question onto your own server, name it as you wish, and then serve it back up to your end users.

Comment: If you host the file, you can specify the save file name as a different name in the HTTP header

Comment: Matthias: based on the original poster, it's apparent he's not hosting the file himself so changing headers is not going to help him, other than performing that instead of changing the filename during his own download process.

Comment: @matthias, yea, it's on a different server

Answer (score 0):

Look into the HTTP header [Content-Disposition](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2183.txt) header, it will allow you to specify the filename.

Comment: Is that something that could be used for remote files which is what raj seems to be pointing at?

Comment: No, you need to funnel the download through some part of your site that can change the HTTP headers on their way, either a web page that changes the headers, and then serves, the file, or you need a handler that will change the download on its way.

Comment: And I just love drive-by downvotes that are done without reason.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use any server side technology like ASP.NET. Where in you put in a button on the page. When the button is clicked it will perform following tasks.

1.) Response.Clear();

2.) Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Nasa.pdf");

3.) Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";

4.) Response.WriteFile(context.Server.MapPath("history.nasa.gov/monograph15b.pdf")); // you need to set the realtively correct path for your application.

Comment: thanks! it seems like this is a similar algorithm to mark's suggestion